# Making a variable accessible outside a function

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, function, react-native

I have this React Native code and I want to use the gameOfTheUser variable (which is created in the arrow function: `userRef. ounce (' value'). then (snapshot =>`) outside this one, in order to be able to continue the different conditions. How to do it? I imagine (and I hope!) that there is a simple solution to this problem.

My RouterScreen.js :

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Text } from 'react-native';
    import fb from '../engine/firebaseConfig';

    export default class RouterScreen extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        fb.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          if (user) {
            var userRef = fb.database().ref('users/' + user.uid);
            userRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
              var gameOfTheUser = snapshot.child('game').val();
              console.log('0 : ' + gameOfTheUser);
            });
            if (gameOfTheUser !== null) {
              console.log('InGame');
              var gameID = gameOfTheUser;
              console.log('1 : ' + gameOfTheUser);
              console.log('1 : ' + gameID);
              navigate('Game', { user, gameID });
            } else {
              console.log('NotInGame');
              navigate('Choose', { user });
            }
          } else {
            navigate('Auth');
          }
        });
      }

      render() {
        return <Text>Hello</Text>;
      }
    }
```

My App.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

// Pages
import RouterScreen from './screens/RouterScreen';
import AuthScreen from './screens/AuthScreen';
import ChooseScreen from './screens/ChooseScreen';
import GameScreen from './screens/GameScreen';

export const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Router: {
      screen: RouterScreen,
    },
    Auth: {
      screen: AuthScreen,
    },
    Choose: {
      screen: ChooseScreen,
    },
    Game: {
      screen: GameScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Router',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootStack />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i can describe your purpose at:

- Login user
- If ingame -> naviage to game
- Else -> navigate to Auth.

There are many way to do this but as "simple" in your question, i think `React Native Async Storage` is a good solution.

> AsyncStorage is a simple, unencrypted, asynchronous, persistent, key-value storage system that is global to the app. It should be used instead of LocalStorage.

See React Native document about Async Storage [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html).

There is some demo codes:

Get data from storage:

```
var gameOfTheUser = AsyncStorage.getItem('gameOfTheUser');
```

Save data to Async Storage:

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem('gameOfTheUser', 'the_witcher_3');
```

> Note: Async storage can only save data with type of String. So with complex data like array or Object you must `JSON.stringify` it first

Comment: Thank you for this solution, you say there are others, can you tell me more? The problem with AsyncStorage is that it slows down the application.

Comment: First, about your purpose to access data outside of function. It can resolve simple by set it to a larger scope variable like _global or Class variable (simple) or use more complex state management system like Redux, Mobx. But, i think your main purpose is store data when application not active and can re-access it when user login. Thus, you need a cache system like Async Storage or other react-native cache  solution. You also save your data online in your database and return it with user data.